# Make a pandas df index continuous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, reindex

I have two pandas dataframes that each contain data about a series of groundwater wells.
(df1) with two columns 'Well Id' and 'Surface_Elevation_mAHD'
(df2) with two columns 'Well Id' and 'Adopted level'

```
# make a df that has the well names, elevation and ss groundwater 
`enter code here`levels
df1 = well_data_all[['Well Id','Surface_Elevation_mAHD']]
df2 = ss_well_data[['Well ID','Adopted']]
```

I want to make a dictionary that will hold information from both df with keys of each well name.

The problem is that there are missing rows of data in each of the df that I need to remove with dropna.  When I do that, the index becomes jumbled and non-continuous.

```
# remove the NaNs or blank values
df1.replace(' ',np.nan,inplace=True)                                     # replace empty spaces with NaNs
df1 = df1.dropna()
```

For example, df1 started with 144 measurments, and before I removed the NaNs, the index went from 1 to 144 but when NaNs are removed, there are 104 measurements and instead of the index being continuous from 1- 104, it goes from 1 - 122 but there are missing index values.
I have tried to reindex, but when I do that, the missing index values reappear with NaNs and when I dropnans, I am left with the same probem of a non continuous index
I have tried:

```
x = range(1,len(df1),1)
ind=[]
for n in x:
    ind.append(n)

new_df = df1.reindex(ind)
```

Any help on how to make the index go from 1 to 104 would be much appreciated.

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked.  I have literally been trying to get that for the last hour, you are a champion and have made my day!

Comment: also `df.index = np.arange(len(df))`.

Comment: Awesome, that works too.  Thanks heaps